# Angular Unit testing - NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe

Tags: angular

I am implementing unit test for a service which have a dependency(Injected) of two more services, here one of the injected service use the Angular DatePipe. so i am using angular Testbed to automate like below, I am getting "NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!" exception when I run the test method.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TaskDetailsService } from './task-details.service';

fdescribe('TaskDetailsService', () => {
  let service: TaskDetailsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(), RouterModule.forRoot([])],
      providers: [TaskDetailsService, DatePipe],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(TaskDetailsService);
  });

  fit('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    expect(service.getPlaceholder(2)).toBe('Find in failed tasks');
  });
});
```

**Error on Karma:**

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have to import a pipe outside a component. There is a design issue here.

Comment: Yup, pipe being used in a service is bad code smell. You're doing something you shouldn't in your service.

Answer (score -1):

Angular's TestBed is unable to find a provider for the DatePipe when configuring the testing module. The DatePipe is a built-in Angular pipe, and it's not a service that you can directly provide using the providers array in TestBed.configureTestingModule.

You can create a mock of the DatePipe for your unit test. This is a good approach if you don't need to test the behavior of the DatePipe itself but just want to ensure that your service interacts with it correctly.

**Option 1** : If you want to perform more integration-like tests, you can go with

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TaskDetailsService } from './task-details.service';

fdescribe('TaskDetailsService', () => {
  let service: TaskDetailsService;
  let datePipeSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<DatePipe>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const datePipeSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('DatePipe', ['transform']);
    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TaskDetailsService,
        { provide: DatePipe, useValue: datePipeSpyObj }
      ],
    });
    
    service = TestBed.inject(TaskDetailsService);
    datePipeSpy = TestBed.inject(DatePipe) as jasmine.SpyObj<DatePipe>;
  });

  fit('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    expect(service.getPlaceholder(2)).toBe('Find in failed tasks');
  });
});
```

**Option 2** : If you want to use the actual DatePipe in your tests, you can configure TestBed to use the real Angular module that provides it.

```
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TaskDetailsService } from './task-details.service';

fdescribe('TaskDetailsService', () => {
  let service: TaskDetailsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CommonModule], // Import CommonModule
      providers: [TaskDetailsService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(TaskDetailsService);
  });

  fit('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    expect(service.getPlaceholder(2)).toBe('Find in failed tasks');
  });
});
```

Hope it's helpful